# Twitter video upload with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am trying to post a video using Twitter modules in NodeJS but I am getting an error - Error 202 “Your credentials do not allow access to this resource”.

Here a snippet of code, it is missing the APPEND and FINISH calls etc but would have expected not to receive an error 202?

Has anyone managed to upload a video using JavaScript than can give me some guidance? I have tried to research and tried several different options.

```
T.post('media/upload', {
    media: data,
    encoding: 'base64',
    command: 'INIT',
    total_bytes: getFilesizeInBytes(image)
}, function(error, media, response) {
    if (!error) {
        var status = {
            status: message
        };

        if(media) status['media_ids'] = media.media_id_string;

        T.post('statuses/update', status, function(error, tweet, response) {
            if(!error) console.log(' -- message sent');
            else console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```